# Facebook Graph API - What is a Check In?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

The documentation for an Open Graph Check-in is available at: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/checkin/ .  I don't understand what it is.  What is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking In, means when you (and your friends) are at location you can 'Check In' to that location by using facebook's list of locations. You can add a location if its not listed, and even add information to those locations. It shows up on your Wall that you 'Checked In' into 'Location X' with 'Friends Y and Z'

This would allow you to grab the users check in's perhaps to see popular locations they like, or determine other things that may be helpful from that information.

Comment: So a sample use case would be, that the User is at a night club and performs a "Check in" via a mobile device to alert friends where he/she is located?

Comment: @smartcaveman Yes that would be an excellent use case. I actually use this feature all the time on my iPhone. I use to tell people where I am and if any of friends are in the area they know they can join me. Rather than sending out like 50 text messages I invite my close friends then 'Check In' to FaceBook and others are free to see and join me.